# Can anyone help me with this problem on pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql, pycryptodome, python-cffi

I was trying to use pymysql to connect to mysql server, but when I was importing it, it throws an error.

It prints

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Python API call failed', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.18.3/src/err/mod.rs:790:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/mysql-8.0.29-macos12-x86_64/etc/Desktop/编程学习/MySQL/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymysql
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from . import connections  # noqa: E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _auth
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives._serialization import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import HashAlgorithm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import openssl as rust_openssl
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
```

I have really no idea about this because I have never seen it before.
Could anyone help me with this?
And also I can run the database on my Mac‘s Terminal.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34370962/5320906), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61314440/5320906). Looks like trying to (re)install `cffi` would be the place to start with this.

Comment: Maybe this one also can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882029/mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-arm64-need-x86-64-i

Comment: Have you tried trying to install the `cffi` module, as suggested in the two links that I provided earlier?

Comment: Yea, and the problem has been solved ! Thank you for your advices and really appreciate !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [certbort commands return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\_cffi\_backend'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314440/certbort-commands-return-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cffi-backend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First check your python version and then check compatibility 64bit or 32bit
2. install mysql.connector module instead of pymysql ( mysql-connector-python)

Comment: Thank you for this answer and that's really helpful ! ! 